# Taking the input(.vrp) and generating the output File(XML) in OptaPlanner without using GUI

Tags: java, optaplanner

```
    Opatestclass op =new Opatestclass();
    VehicleRoutingFileIO io=new VehicleRoutingFileIO();
    VehicleRoutingSolution vrs=new VehicleRoutingSolution();
    vrs=io.read(op.inputFile);
```

In optaplanner, I am solving a VRP problem using with optaplanner without using its GUI. My target program will take an input .vrp file and will generate a solution file. Above program lines read a given input file.

I am looking for some API to run VRP algorithm on my VehicleRoutingSolution(vrs) in optaplanner.

Answer (score 0):

Look for `VehicleRoutingImporter.java` (.vrp) and `VehicleRoutingFileIO.java` (.xml). No UI code needed.